Ubuntu on Docker: "Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C"
Steps to reproduce:

Download macOS docker from https://download.docker.com/mac/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.16.tgz

Extract the file.

Execute the following command:
~/Downloads/docker/docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash


In the containter run:
root@926b2fa67ba4:/# apt-get update



The error is the following:
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C

NOTE: It is a pub key of security.ubuntu.com, and archive.ubuntu.com on the fresh install Ubuntu. It is not the same as How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?. Please help.
I get the error even if I use the GPG key downloaded from
https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x871920D1991BC93C
(I put [signed-by=the key downloaded from the above URL] in /etc/apt/sources.list, e.g.:
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/0x871920D1991BC93C.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-updates main restricted` )


Your problem is that you're trying to install macOS docker which is only for macOS in Ubuntu, so it's giving you a NO_PUBKEY error message. The command to install Docker in Ubuntu is sudo apt install docker.io.
